# How to make parallel build option enable through command line instead of eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, command-line, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to build my eclipse project from command line by giving the below command:

```
eclipsec.exe --launcher.suppressErrors -nosplash -application 
org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data C:\Users\e856690\WS -cleanBuild all
```

Is there any command which I can append to the above line  to make parallel build enable and disable through command line?

Note: I don't want to do it through eclipse IDE

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no official way to turn on/off parallel build from the headlessbuild command line.

The options are:

1) Contribute a patch to CDT to allow that. See org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.HeadlessBuilder for the entry point and command line parser

2) A kludge may work where you edit the .cproject to add/remove `-j8` (or similar) from the make command line before starting Eclipse.

Comment: Ok . Can I check the errors if I give headless build command. Example :- There is a compilation error and I gave the build command from command prompt .How I can come to know in where the exact error is. Because I am only java error code.

Comment: I am unsure how what you are asking here relates to the original question. Please clarify or ask a new question.

Comment: Ok sure no it was not related to original question. I thought I can ask here. Ok I will post a new comments. Thanks.